# TypeError: Cannot set property 'data_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some issue with my js code and I don't know how to fix it 
Here is my code :

```
  $('#btn_valid').click(function(){

    var data = new Array();
    var data_id;
    var data_picture;
    var data_title;
    var data_p_picture;
    var data_p_title;
    var data_s_picture;
    var data_s_title;
    var data_reaction;
    var data_datetime;
    var i = 0;


    $('.cbx_ac:checked').each(function(){

      data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      data_picture = $(this).attr('data-picture');
      data_title= $(this).attr('data-title');
      data_p_picture = $(this).attr('data-p_picture');
      data_p_title = $(this).attr('data-p_title');
      data_s_picture = $(this).attr('data-s_picture');
      data_s_title = $(this).attr('data-s_title');
      data_reaction = $(this).attr('data-reaction');
      data_datetime = $(this).attr('data-datetime');

      console.log(data_id); // I Get a value here ( 2564115647_15498456665 )

      data[i]['data_id'] = data_id;  //Error here :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data_id' of undefined
      i++;

    })
    console.log(data);
  })
```

And I get this error I try to set data[i] = [] but seems not to be the solution  :

```
Error here :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data_id' of undefined
```

Comment: What do you get if you run $('.cbx_ac:checked') in console?

Comment: This is not the correct way of assigning the value to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data[i] is undefined so

**Simply Change**

```
data[i] = {};
data[i]['data_id'] = data_id;
```

```js
$('#btn_valid').click(function(){

    var data = new Array();
    var data_id;
    var data_picture;
    var data_title;
    var data_p_picture;
    var data_p_title;
    var data_s_picture;
    var data_s_title;
    var data_reaction;
    var data_datetime;
    var i = 0;


    $('.cbx_ac:checked').each(function(){

      data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
      data_picture = $(this).attr('data-picture');
      data_title= $(this).attr('data-title');
      data_p_picture = $(this).attr('data-p_picture');
      data_p_title = $(this).attr('data-p_title');
      data_s_picture = $(this).attr('data-s_picture');
      data_s_title = $(this).attr('data-s_title');
      data_reaction = $(this).attr('data-reaction');
      data_datetime = $(this).attr('data-datetime');

      console.log(data_id); // I Get a value here ( 2564115647_15498456665 )
       data[i] = {};
      data[i]['data_id'] = data_id;  //Error here :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data_id' of undefined
      i++;
   

    })
    console.log(data);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" id="btn_valid" value="Click Me" />
<input type="checkbox" data-id="data-id" data-picture="pic1" data-title="title1" id="scales" class="cbx_ac" name="feature"
               value="scales" checked />
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is because `data[i]` is `undefined`. You're therefore attempting to set a property of `undefined`, hence the error.

To fix this you need to first create an object in `data[i]`, like this:

```
data[i] = {};
data[i]['data_id'] = data_id;
// and so on...
```

*However* it is worth noting that you can *massively* simplify this logic and DRY it up. When you access the `data()` method of an element it will return all its attributes in an object. As such, so long as the attribute names match the property names of the object you want to create, you can just apply that to an array using `map()`:

```js
$('#btn_valid').click(function() {
  var data = $('.cbx_ac:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).data();
  }).get();
  console.log(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cbx_ac" data-id="id1" data-picture="pic1" data-title="title1" checked="true" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cbx_ac" data-id="id2" data-picture="pic2" data-title="title2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cbx_ac" data-id="id3" data-picture="pic3" data-title="title3" checked="true" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cbx_ac" data-id="id4" data-picture="pic4" data-title="title4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cbx_ac" data-id="id5" data-picture="pic5" data-title="title5" />

<button id="btn_valid">Test</button>
```

Note that the example above is missing some of the `data` attributes in the HTML, but that's just for brevity. You can easily add them all in your production version.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error as data[i] is not defined as an array.

if you define

```
    data[i] = {};
```

after that below statement will work.

```
    data[i]['data_id'] = data_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it to a `Map` first:

```
data[i] = new Map();
data[i]['data_id'] = data_id;
```